# NHibernate, joined subclass hierarchy, PreUpdate event data changes on an entity which is only modified in the PreUpdate event is not persisted

Tags: nhibernate

**Overview**: With NHibernate I am experimenting with a 3 layered hierarchy using joined subclasses.  There is a Category, which inherits from AuditableEntity (to add PreUpdate and PreInsert audit trail), which finally inherits from an Entity.

**Problem**: None of the data changes to the AuditableEntity object, which are carried out exactly as Ayende’s blog post, are being persisted to the database.  The AuditableEntity objects properties are successfully updated by the PreUpdate code, but it is as if NHibernate is not seeing the AuditableEntity as dirty as no update sql statement occurs.

**Hbm**:

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="Learning"
                   namespace="Learning.entities">
  <class name="Entity" >
    <id name="Id" type="guid">
      <generator class="guid.comb"></generator>
    </id>
    <version name="Version"/>

    <joined-subclass name="AuditableEntity" >
      <key column="AuditableEntity_id"></key>

      <property name="CreatedOn" ></property>
      <property name="CreatedBy" ></property>
      <property name="LastModifiedOn" ></property>
      <property name="LastModifiedBy" ></property>

      <joined-subclass name="Category">
        <key column="AuditableEntity_id"></key>
        <property name="Name" />
      </joined-subclass>

    </joined-subclass>    
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**NHibernate config for listeners**:

```
<event type="pre-insert">
  <listener class="Learning.eventlisteners.AuditInsertEventListener, Learning" />
</event>
<event type="pre-update">
  <listener class="Learning.eventlisteners.AuditUpdateEventListener, Learning" />
</event>
```

**PreUpdate code**:

```
namespace Learning.eventlisteners
{
    public class AuditInsertEventListener : IPreInsertEventListener
    {
        public bool OnPreInsert(PreInsertEvent @event)
        {
            var audit = @event.Entity as IAuditable;
            if (audit == null)
                return false;

            var createdOn = DateTime.Now;
            var createdBy = loggedOnProfile;

            AuditCommon.Set(@event.Persister, @event.State, "CreatedOn", createdOn);
            AuditCommon.Set(@event.Persister, @event.State, "CreatedBy", createdBy);
            AuditCommon.Set(@event.Persister, @event.State, "LastModifiedOn", createdOn);
            AuditCommon.Set(@event.Persister, @event.State, "LastModifiedBy", createdBy);

            audit.CreatedOn = createdOn;
            audit.CreatedBy = createdBy;
            audit.LastModifiedOn = createdOn;
            audit.LastModifiedBy = createdBy;

            return false;
        }
    }

    public static class AuditCommon
    {
        internal static void Set(IEntityPersister persister, IList<object> state, string propertyName, object value)
        {
            var index = Array.IndexOf(persister.PropertyNames, propertyName);
            if (index == -1)
                return;
            state[index] = value;
        }
    }

    public class AuditUpdateEventListener : IPreUpdateEventListener
    {
        public bool OnPreUpdate(PreUpdateEvent @event)
        {
            var audit = @event.Entity as IAuditable;
            if (audit == null)
                return false;

            var lastModifiedOn = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(28);
            var lastModifiedBy = loggedOnProfile;

            AuditCommon.Set(@event.Persister, @event.State, "LastModifiedOn", lastModifiedOn);
            AuditCommon.Set(@event.Persister, @event.State, "LastModifiedBy", lastModifiedBy);

            audit.LastModifiedOn = lastModifiedOn;
            audit.LastModifiedBy = lastModifiedBy;

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**Code**:

```
using (var session = SessionFactory.OpenSession())
using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    var category = session.Query<Category>().First();
    category.Name = "Updated";
    session.SaveOrUpdate(category);
    transaction.Commit();
}
```

**An observation**: if I manually update just one of the AuditableEntity properties before calling SaveOrUpdate, the PreUpdate event is obviously fired and appropriate data changes are made, and then the AuditableEntity data IS persisted to the database.

```
using (var session = SessionFactory.OpenSession())
using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    var category = session.Query<Category>().First();
    category.Name = "Updated";
    category.CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;
    session.SaveOrUpdate(category);
    transaction.Commit();
}
```

**Help**: I obviously don't want to have to dummy edit an AuditableEntity properties, so any ideas as to what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: I'm confused. Why would you expect the PreUpdate even to fire on an unmodified Category? Or do you mean the AuditableEntity fields on Category inherited by Category? Also show your PreUpdate/PreInsert listeners please.

Comment: Hi James, thanks for your comment.  So sorry I pasted the wrong c# update code.  Fully amended with listeners too.  So any ideas why the AuditableEntity properties are not saved despite the Category being updated.  The Category inherits from AuditableEntity.  Thanks.

Comment: Can you try setting the CreatedOn property to a value which isn't close to what the auditor is using to see which value is being persisted?  ie does nh use the audit's value or the value set by the 'normal' code?

Comment: And total guess: debug if your update event is prematurely returning during AuditCommon.Set() method, maybe you have to add the property into the state list as nh previous to this point didn't see the property as dirty so its not in there?

Comment: Hi Noel, thanks for your comment.  When setting a value in the "normal" code, then the auditor runs in the correct order, it is the auditor's values which are persisted.

Comment: I've repro'd the problem and it appears to be a bug in NHibernate. I would suggest submitting a bug report with repro to jira.nhforge.org.

Comment: Hi James, thanks for your confirmation.  I have raised a NHibernate bug report - http://216.121.112.228/browse/NH-2617

Comment: I have added a further message on the NHuser group to get a conclusion to this - http://groups.google.com/group/nhusers/browse_thread/thread/b6807c2a486073d8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer this I have authored an nhibernate.info WIKI article - http://nhibernate.info/doc/howto/various/changing-values-in-nhibernate-events

The **abstract**; Audit trails using NHibernate's event model often use the OnPreInsert and OnPreUpdate event listeners to change/ modify the state of the entity.  While this does works and is widely documented as a solution, it should be noted the OnPreInsert and OnPreUpdate events are not intended to be used to change the values of the entity and instead they should be used to check values and for that reason they return "veto".

**An update** blog post from Fabio - http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/2011/05/nhibernate-bizarre-audit.html